# Is discrete log as hard when given same challenge in both pairing groups, in the case of BN curve and its sextic twist

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

This is a special case of the question 
[Generalization of the DL-assumption in bilinear group pair](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31312/generalization-of-the-dl-assumption-in-bilinear-group-pair),
that wasn't answered.

Suppose $G_1$ is a BN curve over $F_q$. That is the set of elements
$(x,y)\in F_q^2$ such that 
$$y^2 =x^3+b$$
for appropriately chosen $b$.
and $G_2$ is a sextic twist of $G_1$.
That is, the set of elements $(x,y)\in F_{q^2}^2$ such that
$y^2=x^3+b/\xi,$
where $\xi\in F_{q^2}$ is such that $W^6-\xi$ is irreducible over $F_{q^2}$.

Given $(P,s\cdot P)\in G_1^2$ 
and $(Q,s\cdot Q)\in G_2^2$
is it hard to find $s$?
Is it as hard as when given only one of the two pairs?